# Pass Parameter To Controller Using URL.ACTION

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using Jquery I am trying to pass a date parameter from a datepicker using `URL.Action` to a Kendo Chart.  But I cant figure out how to add the variable into the url, see below.

View:

```
var myDate = $(inpDateCompleted).val();  

// How to get myDate into the below line to replace 01/11/2013:
var url = '@(Url.Action("HoursByDay", "DashBoard", new { dateCompleted= "01/11/2013" }, null))';

$("#chart").kendoChart({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            sort: {
                field: "Date",
                dir: "asc"
            }
        },
        /// Rest of chart setup removed for clarity
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult HoursByDay(DateTime dateCompleted)
{
        var s = ExecuteSqlCommand2(dateCompleted);            
        return Content(s, "application/json");
}
```

Comment: You method parameter is named `dateCompleted` so it needs to be `new { dateCompleted = "01/11/2013" }`

Comment: Just noticed that you want to assign a javascript variable to it. Razor code is parsed on the server before its passes to the view so you need to build the url using javascript (modify the `href` value or use `location.ref = ` to redirect.

Comment: Thanks Stephen I have corrected the first issue. Could you elaborate further on the last part. "modify the href value or use location.ref = to redirect"

Comment: `var url = '@(Url.Action("HoursByDay", "DashBoard")' + '?dateCompleted=' + myDate;`

Comment: For some reason it looks kind of hacky to my untrained eye is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your query string name matches with your action method parameter name

```
var url = '@Url.Action("HoursByDay", "DashBoard", 
                                           new { dateCompleted= "01/11/2013" })';
alert(url);
```

If you want to pass a javascript variable value as the value for dateCompleted param, You should first build the url to the action method (without any parameters) and append the querystring value in javascript.

```
var myDate = $(#yourInputFieldIdForDate").val();
alert(myDate); 
var url = '@Url.Action("HoursByDay", "DashBoard")?dateCompleted=' + myDate;
alert(url);
```

Replace the jQuery selector to get the date value to suit to your requirements.